# What d10 RPG is this cat playing?

Tags: product-identification

A friend posted this funny image.  There is a cat with a character sheet of a game.  There is a pool of 10 d10s on it.
It isn't clear enough for me to figure out what game it is.
[image: A medium hair gray tabby cat sits at a table before a character sheet and a pile of 10-sided dice. The caption reads " 'The wizard places a chalice on the table, filled with a strange, smoking liquid. He cautions that this potion is incredibly danger-' 'I knock it over.' "]

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Exalted 3rd Edition from Onyx Path Publishing. The Storyteller system in general tend to use d10 dice pools and several of the stats ("Willpower") listed, while the term "Solar Experience" and "Limit Trigger" are specific to the 3rd Edition of the Exalted RPG.

The precise character sheet in use is the official Solar Exalted sheet and can be found [here](https://mrgone.rocksolidshells.com/pdf/Exalted/Exalted3rdED_2-Page_Demo_Interactive.pdf):

[image: Screen shot of character sheet PDF matching the photo in the question]

You can see the Solar Experience section, as well as the texture (blood spatter?) along the bottom edge of the page.